# Jest mock submodule function

Tags: node.js, express, testing, mocking, jestjs

I have this node module called `client`. It has the following structure:

```
//index.js
import users from "./users"

export default { users }
```

And:

```
//users.js
export default { getUser }
function getUser(username) {
    ...
    return {role: userRole}  
}
```

I want to mock this getUser(username) function in my tests.
So I could call something like:

```
client.users.getUser.mockResolvedValueOnce({role: "manager"})
```

My test header is like:

```
let client = jest.genMockFromModule('client').default;
client.users.getUser = jest.fn();
```

But, running my test, I get the following error when my original code call `client.users.getUser`.

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined
>
>   58 | 
>   59 |     // Retrieve user and then return its projects
> > 60 |     client.users.getUser(username)
>      |                  ^
>   61 |         .then(user => {
>   62 |             if (!user) {
>   63 |                 throw new Error(`User ${username} not found`)
>
>   at Object.getUser (node_modules/client/build/users.js:26:45)
>   at Object.getUser [as insert] (src/web/controller/projects.js:60:18)
>   at Object.insert (src/web/controller/projects.test.js:80:18)
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can just mock the `//users.js` module like this:

```
jest.mock('./users.js', () => ({getUser: () => ({role: "manager"})})) //note that the path is relative to the test
```

if you need different return values during your tests you can mock it to return a spy and set the mock return value in the tests:

```
import {getUsers} from './users'
jest.mock('./users.js', () => ({getUser: jest.fn()})) 

it('does something', () => {
 getUser.mockImplementation(() => ({role: "manager"}))
})
it('does something else', () => {
 getUser.mockImplementation(() => ({role: "user"}))
})
```

Comment: But I don't think I can mock users like that. Because I'm testing another module:  projects. (Thanks!)

Comment: That doesn't matter. You can mock every module and will be replaced by the mock.

Comment: I'm trying here: 
import {getUsers} from 'client/users'
jest.mock('client/users.js', () => ({getUser: jest.fn()})) 

But I'm getting:
Cannot find module 'client/users.js' from 'projects.test.js'

Comment: looks like the path is wrong, usually a relative path starts with `./`

Comment: I've made it work with:

jest.mock('client', () => ({
    users: {
        getUser: jest.fn()
    }
}));

And:
    test.only("block manager role", done => {
        clients.users.getUser.mockImplementation(() => {
            return Promise.resolve({role: "manager"})
        })

There's another way instead of mocking full module (as you suggested) ?
What I'm trying to say is: this relative path isn't working. 
Maybe isn't working because is a external module.